# How is "quant à lui" being used in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire

I came upon this sentence:

> Le nom avenir quant à lui renvoie à quelque chose de plus concret, de plus proche.

*Quant à lui* seems oddly placed here. I translate this in my head as "As for the noun *avenir*, it refers to something more concrete, more imminent." But if I were translating this back to French, I would write "Quant au nom *avenir*, il renvoie..."

Their phrasing seems to echo complex inversion. Why is *quant à lui* used here rather than my phrasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Quant à* : Pour ce qui est de, relativement à (telle personne, chose ou question sur laquelle se fixe un moment l'attention) - Le Robert

Il s'agit donc d'attirer l'attention sur le *nom avenir* objet de l'étude et de préciser son sens, sa portée, la signification que l'auteur à voulu donner à ce mot.

De ce fait, on souligne la focalisation de la pensée en faisant suivre le mot par *quant à lui*.

On peut aussi reformuler la phrase en changeant la place de *quant à* par rapport à l'objet étudié :

> *Quant au nom avenir*, il renvoie ...